# Set multiple JFrames independent of one another

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have two `JFrame` windows, I want to turn off one, but when I `click_on_close` one, both of them turn off. What is the solution for me?

[image: JFrame close single window]

Comment: Update your question with some of code. Your on_close method at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close a single of your two JFrames without exiting your application try this:

```
frameToClose.setVisible(false);
frameToClose.dispose();
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) The second 'frame' should be a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane`. 2) But if using multiple frames makes sense, the correct path is most likely `theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing:

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

If so, you may want to change this.

Comment: When I click the ADD button, the "ADD new Customers" window appears. I want to turn off the "ADD new Customers" window, but I want to keep the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make one windows invisible if you want to.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question; it is better suited as a comment.